# Bind object data to Int xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a MasterDetailPage that creates several Department objects.  I want to grab the current department number so I can use it to sort a list later on in my program.  How do I go about doing that?  I have tried binding it to a label and then getting the data from that (very hacky, I know) but that's the only thing I could think of.

```
Department[] departments = {
            new Department ("D", 1), 
            new Department ("De", 7),
            new Department ("G", 4),
            new Department ("M", 9),
            new Department ("Pr", 167),
            new Department ("Fr", 187),
            new Department ("H", 169),
            new Department ("B", 11),
            new Department ("S", 399),
            new Department ("N", 407),
            new Department ("O", 201),
            new Department ("U", 023)
        };

        ListView listView = new ListView {
            ItemsSource = departments
        };

        this.Master = new ContentPage {
            Title = "Departments",       // Title required!
            Content = new StackLayout {
                Children = {
                    header, 
                    listView
                }
            }
        };

        DetailPage2 detailPage = new DetailPage2 ();
        this.Detail = detailPage;  //detail page is where I want to                  use deptNum for sorting

        listView.ItemSelected += (sender, args) => {
            // Set the BindingContext of the detail page.
            this.Detail.BindingContext = args.SelectedItem;

            // Show the detail page.
            this.IsPresented = false;

        };

        // Initialize the ListView selection.
        listView.SelectedItem = departments [0];

    }
    }
}
```

Then in my detailpage I want to be able to pull the departmentNumber out and use it as an int

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace irisxamarin
{
  public class Department :BindableObject
   {
    public Department (string name, int deptNumber)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.DeptNum = deptNumber;


    }

    public string Name { private set; get; }

    public int DeptNum { private set; get; }

    public override string ToString ()
    {
        return Name;
    }
 }
}
```

And here is some logic in the detailpage.  This is where I would like to grab the current deptNum.

```
namespace irisxamarin
{
public class DetailPage2 : ContentPage
{
    public DetailPage2 ()
    {

        Request request = new Request ();

        Button settingsButton = new Button {
            Text = "Settings",
            TextColor = Color.Gray
        };

 //......................
//code above and below


ListView itemsList = new ListView { 
            ItemsSource = request.GetList (deptNum) //USE INT HERE

        };

        itemsList.ItemSelected += (sender, args) => {

            this.BindingContext = args.SelectedItem;
        };

        itemLabel.SetBinding (Label.TextProperty, "DeptNum");
    //DeptNum is the data I want but not in a label, just the int val         

        var listFrame = new Frame {
            Content = itemsList,
            OutlineColor = Color.Silver,

        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Each page is just a C# class.  You can pass a value to it the way you would do with any class - generally the easiest way is to

1. pass values in the constructor
2. or if the page already exists, create public properties and set the value via the setter

If you want to set a value globally for use throughout your app, you can create a static class that is available everywhere and set state values in that class.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that.  However I want the Department number to be reactive if the user changes the Department during the app.

Comment: Use INotifyPropertyChanged to allow dependent pages to be notified of changes in the value of a property.

Comment: Cool,  I'm looking into that option.  I still don't understand how I can get the current department number in my detail page once it changes.  Can I just pull it out and save it to an int?  I don't want to use the data in a label or another object, I just strictly need the integer to pass to a class which can the sort a list for me.  I do think this is the right approach, I'm just new to xamarin and I don't quite understand how the event handler's are working.

Comment: I have tried passing the value through the constructor to the detail page but no dice, the program crashes.

Comment: I got it to work by passing the int value/deptnum, but the app doesn't react the the department changing since I passed the value to the page.  The set binding context works perfectly with a label etc, but How do you extract that data from the label once it is assigned?